# Wordpress local vs. online array

Tags: php, wordpress, local

I have worked on my wordpress local and will put et online.. under one of my pages the site should show like in this images. but i don't??

i have tried to overwrite to file over and over , but i won't help
The pages have the right custom fields..

http://i58.tinypic.com/14u9sg5.png

```
<div class="main">
<?php

    $categoriesCF = get_post_meta($post->ID, "categories", true);
    // example value = "PREVIOUS|35, SCHEDULE|37"

    $allCategories = explode(",", $categoriesCF);
    // $allCategories[0] = "PREVIOUS|35"
    // $allCategories[1] = "SCHEDULE|37"

    foreach ($allCategories as $category) {

        $pieces = explode("|", $category);
        // $pieces[0] = "SCHEDULE"
        // $pieces[1] = 37

        $link = get_permalink($pieces[1]);

        echo "<div class='mission-post'>";
        echo "<h3><a href='$link'>" . $pieces[0] . "</a></h3>";


        query_posts("posts_per_page=-1&post_type=page&post_parent=$pieces[1]");

        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="product-jump" title="<?php echo "$" . get_post_meta($post->ID, "title", true); ?>" data-large="<?php get_post_meta($post->ID, "mission_lille", true); ?>">



            <?php echo "<img src='" . get_post_meta($post->ID, "mission_lille", true) . "'/>"; ?>

            <span class="product-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            <span class="product-code">Location:<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "location", true); ?></span>
            <span class="product-code">Type:<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "type", true); ?></span>
            <span class="product-code">Date:<?php echo get_post_meta($post-    >ID, "date", true); ?></span>

            <p><b>Read More</b></p>

            </a>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();

        echo "</div>";

    };
?>
```

Comment: Your db on online server is up to date? I mean db records is same as your local?

Comment: In your code, you are getting something from db. If that data is not in online, page cannot be shown correctly. That is possible

Comment: okay... so if i export my date and importe to the server i should work?

Comment: If the codebase is same, it should work

Comment: okay.. i'm not sure have to do it, but will try.. thanks..

Comment: hmm it will not work.. if i remove the custom field "categories" it shows what i want but it also add the menu´s to a block

http://i60.tinypic.com/ek13qd.png

Comment: i fixed it.. i called the wrong id! :P